# Let us define a series $\{a(n)\}$ such that $a(n)= a(n-1) + \frac{1}{a(n-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let us define a series $\{a(n)\}$ such that 
$a(n)= a(n-1) + \frac{1}{a(n-1)}$  and $a(1)=1$

then prove that $a(75)$ belongs to the interval $(12,15)$

note here i have used $X(n)$ where n is in  sub script denoting the  series count.

Im unable to think..
what i have done is i have added all the terms as $\{ a(n)-a(1)\}$ which gave me:
$a(n)-a(1)=\frac{1}{a(1)} +\frac{1}{a(2)}+\frac{1}{a(3)}......+\frac{1}{a(n-1)}$

i tried am-gm inequality but it is of no help.

Please Help .

Comment: what is (12,15),?

Comment: @BAYMAX Probably the interval $(12, 15)$.

Comment: it is interval in which a(75) lies

Comment: This was asked several times on the site, and the answer below reproduces computations already presented. The idea to compare $a_n^2$ to $2n$ comes from the fact that the corresponding differential equation $$x'(t)=\frac1{x(t)}$$ is solved by $$x(t)^2=2t+x(0)^2$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice first that

$$ a_n^2 = a_{n-1}^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{a_{n-1}^2} > a_{n-1}^2 + 2. \tag{*}$$

Recursively applying this inequality and using the fact that $a_2 = 2$,

$$ \forall n \geq 2, \qquad a_n^2 \geq 2n \tag{1} $$

Now plugging this inequality back to $\text{(*)}$, for $n \geq 3$ we have

$$ a_n^2 \leq a_{n-1}^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{2(n-1)} $$

with strict inequality when $n \geq 3$. Recursively applying this inequality yields

$$ a_n^2
\leq a_2^2 + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \left(2 + \frac{1}{2k} \right)
= 2n + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2k} \tag{2} $$

When $n = 75$, we obtain a lower bound from $\text{(1)}$:

$$ 12^2
< 150
\leq a_{75}^2 $$

and an upper bound from $\text{(2)}$:

$$ a_{75}^2
\leq 150 + \sum_{k=2}^{74} \frac{1}{2k}
< 150 + \frac{\log 74}{2}
< 150 + \frac{\log_2 128}{2}
< 169
= 13^2. $$

This proves that $ 12 < a_{75} < 13 $ and hence the claim follows.

Comment: It is enough for the upper bound to use $a_n^2=a_{n-1}^2+2+1/a_{n-1}^2<a_{n-1}^2+3$ so $a_n^2<3n$.

Comment: @guest, You are right. Indeed, the interval is cooked up so that even such a crude bound works to yield a proof.